# Swift alternative to respondsToSelector:

Tags: swift

I was trying to implement swift's alternative to the `respondsToSelector:` syntax that was also shown in the keynote.

I have the following:

```
protocol CustomItemTableViewCellDelegate {
    func changeCount(sender: UITableViewCell, change: Int)
}
```

and then later in the code I call

```
class CustomItemTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

   var delegate: CustomItemTableViewCellDelegate
   ...
   override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
      ...
      delegate?.changeCount?(self, change: -1)
   }
   ...
}
```

I get the following errors

- `Operand of postfix '?' should have optional type; type is
  '(UITableViewCell, change:Int) -> ()'`
- `Operand of postfix '?' should
  have optional type; type is 'CustomItemTableViewCellDelegate'`
- `Partial application of protocol method is not allowed`

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have two `?` operators, and they're both causing problems.

First, the one after `delegate` indicates that you want to unwrap an optional value, but your `delegate` property isn't declared that way. It should be:

```
var delegate: CustomItemTableViewCellDelegate?
```

Second, it looks like you want your `changeCount` protocol method to be optional. If you do, you need to both mark the protocol with the `@objc` attribute and mark the function with the `optional` attribute:

```
@objc protocol CustomItemTableViewCellDelegate {
    optional func changeCount(sender: UITableViewCell, change: Int)
}
```

(**Note:** Classes that conform to `@objc` protocols need to be `@objc` themselves. In this case you're subclassing an Objective-C class, so you're covered, but a new class would need to be marked with the `@objc` attribute.)

If you only want the delegate to be optional (that is, it's okay to not have a delegate, but all delegates need to implement `changeCount`), then leave your protocol as is and change that method call to:

```
delegate?.changeCount(self, change: -1)
```

Comment: Great answer. Is there any official documentation on this that you know of? I have been looking for this information for a long time!

Comment: Apple's Swift book has a short section about [optional requirements for protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-XID_415), and a chapter on [optional chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH21-XID_356).

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all.

You use `?` on an explicit type, it can't be `nil`, so simply don't use `?` on that variable.

If you have a var like this one

```
var changeCount: Int
```

or this

```
var changeCount = 3
```

You have an explicit type. When an explicit type is requested, then you should give an explicit type, which is `changeCount` and not `changeCount?`.

If you want optional variable to begin with, declare it with an `?`:

```
var changeCount: Int?
```

You can't use literal syntax with optional type if the type should be implicit. Because 3 is always explicit Int if not stated otherwise.

Comment: How can I make the `delegate` optional?

Comment: @Casper `var delegate: CustomItemTableViewCellDelegate?`