# iOS Local Notification [SWIFT] support for 7.0 & 8.0

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I'm working on an App that I'd like to deploy at 7.0

The application uses UILocalNotifications.

With iOS8.0 I understand that I need to run the following so that notifications can be triggered:

```
application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: UIUserNotificationType.Sound | UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge, categories: nil))
```

Trouble is "application.registerUserNotificationSettings" is only available for iOS8.0.

I've currently got this included and the deployment set to 7.0 and there are no warnings. Will this be ok?

Swift doesn't seem to use "respondstoselector" so I'm unable to check.

Comment: `responseToSelector` is part of the NSObject protocol and that *is* available in Swift, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167791/what-is-the-swift-equivalent-of-respondstoselector.

Comment: This looks perfect. Thanks very much.

I realised I need to download the Simulator version 7.0 to actually have the iOS7.0 installed. So this will be a good test later.