# What is the best way to call optional delegate functions in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

What is the best way to call optional delegate functions in Swift?

Suppose that I have the following protocol:

```
@objc protocol SomeDelegate {

    optional func someOptionalFunction(sender: AnyObject)

}
```

and I have the class that looks like this:

```
class Foo {

    var delegate: SomeDelegate! = nil

    func someFunction(email: String, password: String) {
        self.delegate.someOptionalFunction?(self)
    }

}
```

Should I call it like this or not? If not, what is the best practice to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the [optional chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html) is one of the most common patterns in swift, so, IMHO you are doing this in the right way

Answer (score 2):

The "`?`" bit in that call is what makes it safe to call, whether the optional delegate is implemented or not.  That's all I would do in my own code.

If you absolutely wanted to be certain `someOptionalFunction` exists,  [you could always use `respondsToSelector`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167791/what-is-the-swift-equivalent-of-respondstoselector), which exists for every `NSObject` instance.  But it's almost certainly overkill.

Comment: While the question mark-after-method-name is described in "Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C" I can't find documentation on this in "The Swift Programming Language". Do you, by chance, have a reference?

Comment: [Here's the "Optional Chaining" section of Apple's Swift Programming language doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH21-XID_368). I think what you're asking for is the "Calling Methods Through Optional Chaining" bit?

Comment: Yeah, I've been looking at exactly this piece. But I can't find any mention of the `method?()` call syntax wich dynamically checks if the method is implemented.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe here it is: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-XID_6

Comment: @rintaro Thanks, but I was looking for a proper documentation of the feature (in the Swift book). I wan't to know the name of the feature and if it's considered a part of optional chaining.

Answer (score 1):

`someOptionalFunction?(self)` is absolutely OK. but...

*Basically*, the reference to the delegate should be `weak` and Optional.

```
class Foo {

    weak var delegate: SomeDelegate? = nil
//  ^^^^                           ^  
    func someFunction(email: String, password: String) {
        self.delegate?.someOptionalFunction?(self)
//                   ^
    }
}
```

Comment: There are exceptions to this rule (some prominent ones in Apple's frameworks).