# Property setter responseToSelector

Tags: ios, swift

How to check in Swift whether an instance have a given property setter or not?

Especially, what is the correct Selector in the case below? (This method of the cell does exist in iOS8 but does not exist in iOS7, so I want to check it).

```
if self.respondsToSelector(Selector("setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:")) {
    self.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false;
}
```

Comment: The selector is correct, I don't see the problem here o0

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167791/what-is-the-swift-equivalent-of-respondstoselector

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

var shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

// Option #1
if shapeLayer.responds(to: #selector(setter: CAShapeLayer.drawsAsynchronously)) {
    shapeLayer.drawsAsynchronously = true
}

// Option #2
if #available(iOS 6.0, *) {
    shapeLayer.drawsAsynchronously = true
}
```

Note: Property 'drawsAsynchronously' of CAShapeLayer class is available from iOS 6.0

```
@available(iOS 6.0, *)
open var drawsAsynchronously: Bool
```