# Swift Collections With Class Conforming to Protocol

Tags: swift

Is it possible to construct a collection (array, dictionary, set) type checks values against both a class and a protocol? Given:

```
class Piece {
  var name: String?
}

protocol Jump {
  func jump() { ... }
}

protocol Move {
  func move() { ... }
}
```

Allows:

```
var pieces: [Piece]?
```

Or:

```
 var moves: [Move]?
 var jumps: [Jump]?
```

Or:

```
 var movenjump: [protocol <Move,Jump>]
```

But, I'm not sure how to restrict a collection to instances of `Piece` that `Move` and `Jump`.

Comment: You should get some ideas from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30398786/check-if-optional-protocol-method-is-implemented-in-swift, or you can just create *delegates* for each protocol and check  whether they're nil or not.

Comment: I'd look for generics with a where clause: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GenericParametersAndArguments.html something like let movenjump: Array<Piece where Piece:Move, Piece:Jump>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no. To date, Swift only allow collections for either a single Class type or protocol types (single protocol or multiple protocols). But there are ways you can workaround this.

1. The **best** approach is if `Piece` is your code, try to make it a protocol. Then you can declare array for example: `let anArray: [protocol<Piece, Move, Jump>]`.
2. If you don't have access to the source code of `Piece`, try to generify the surrounding class which needs to declare the collection. This way, you can use `where` clause to constrain the generic type to anything you like:

   ```
   class MyClass<T where T: Piece, T: Move, T: Jump> {
       var myCollection: [T]?
   }
   ```