# CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization() not working on ios7 using swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working with swift 2.0 and on a project that has the deployment target as 7.0. And when I use

```
location.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
```

error is thrown . And I know this particular method isn't there for ios 7. my Question is .. If i add

```
@available(ios 8.0 , *)
```

Would it work on devices with ios 7.0 or this particular function would be processed only if the device is >= ios 8.0 ? Kindly help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167791/what-is-the-swift-equivalent-of-respondstoselector ?

Comment: @Larme, I have gone through that answer , but could not understand clearly . So can u please make it a little clear ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The particular function will be processed only if the device is >= iOS 8.0.**

```
if #available(iOS 8, *)
{
    location.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
} 
else
{
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

Using this will call `requestAlwaysAuthorization()` for devices running on iOS 8+, otherwise it will call `startUpdatingLocation()`.

Comment: I'm checking this as well @ebby94 if (location.respondsToSelector(Selector(location.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()))‌​) . how do i check that ?

Comment: You can't use `requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` in devices running on iOS 7 and lower. Even if you use the `respondsToSelector` method, Xcode will throw an error if your deployment target is lower than iOS 8 and will ask you to fix it with `if #available(iOS 8, *)`.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS7, `CLLocationManager` requests location authorisation to the user when calling `startUpdatingLocation`. Usually, on a iOS7 compatible application, you end up writing

```
if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
  locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
}
locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

This way, location authorisation is requested either by `requestAlwaysAuthorization` or `startUpdatingLocation` depending on the OS.

Comment: I'm checking this as well @tomahh        if (location.respondsToSelector(Selector(location.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()))) . how do i check that ?

Comment: As of Swift 2, the recommended way to check for API availability is through #available() statement. See [this apple blog post](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=29) (under the availability title) for details.