# Swift: Unable to set property value on mutable object paramter

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have the following code:

```
func enableDelaysContentTouchesIncudlingSubviews(enable: Bool) {
    self.setDelaysContentTouches(enable, forObject: self)
    for obj: AnyObject in self.subviews {
        self.setDelaysContentTouches(enable, forObject: obj)
    }
}

private func setDelaysContentTouches(var value: Bool, var forObject obj: AnyObject) {
    if obj.respondsToSelector("setDelaysContentTouches:") {
        obj.delaysContentTouches = value
    }
}
```

On the second function, the line `obj.delaysContentTouches = value` raises the following error:  `Cannot assign to property: 'obj' is immutable`

I don't understand the reason since `obj` is declared as a `var` parameter. Therefor it should be mutable in my understanding.

Could somebody please explain me the reason and also provide a workaround.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is it's an issue of AnyObject technically being a protocol

Assuming you're working in a view, maybe try something along these lines:

```
func enableDelaysContentTouchesIncudlingSubviews(enable: Bool) {
    self.setDelaysContentTouches(enable, view: self)
    self.subviews.forEach({setDelaysContentTouches(enable, view: $0)})
}

private func setDelaysContentTouches(enable: Bool, view: UIView) {
    if let viewAsScrollview = view as? UIScrollView {
        viewAsScrollview.delaysContentTouches = enable;
    }
}
```

This is a much swiftier way of doing things, more clear, and doesn't use "respondsToSelector"

More info, and possibly a more direct answer about respondsToSelector in swift [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167791/what-is-the-swift-equivalent-of-respondstoselector#24168825)

Comment: Yeah you're right, he's trying to access delaysContentTouches on AnyObject while that is a protocol and doesn't even have the delaysContentTouches property. Only a UIScrollView class or subclass has that property. How he does not even receive any errors astonishes me. XCode is probably giving the wrong error too.

Comment: nice, this code works and solved my problem. thanks for the "swiftification" :-)