# When to use respondsToSelector in swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, class, protocols

My question is more of a general question rather than a specific problem. It appears that for a class that is written in Swift, you can use the optional workflow to verify if the method does exist(?). If it doesn't, you can assume it returned `nil`.

This appears only to apply if the class is written in Swift. (Is that a correction assumption)?

Now, if you are referencing an Objective-C class and want to check to see if a method exists, you can use the `respondsToSelector` check with the selector `#selector`.

Is this meant to only be used on Objective-C classes and Swift classes, protocols, protocol /class extensions that inherit from Objective-C classes?

Let me know if I should expand on any part of my questions.

Comment: Please check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167791/what-is-the-swift-equivalent-of-respondstoselector

Comment: Thank you.i guess when checking if a protocol method has been implemented, it's still based on whether the type conforms to nsobject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is scarcely *any* need to call `respondsToSelector` explicitly in Swift. The only time when you'd want to do it is in dealing with an NSObject, and in that case, it is presumably an AnyObject or a delegate protocol adopter, and in either case you can just use question-mark syntax (which calls `respondsToSelector` for you).

Comment: But when you implement a cocoa class or sub class, you are still dealing with nsobject, correct? I guess I am not a 100% sure if all cocoa classes have been converted to swift. Thank you everyone for your input!!

Comment: @cmarti1138: Yes, Cocoa classes are Objective-C classes, so their methods are Objective-C methods, and you can use the optional mechanism with `AnyObject` to call those methods if they respond. If your question is how to do that if the type of the expression is not `AnyObject`, you can cast it to `AnyObject` first: `(... as AnyObject).method?(...)`

Answer (score 0):

> It appears that for a class that is written in Swift, you can use the
>   optional workflow to verify if the method does exist(?). If it
>   doesn't, you can assume it returned nil.
>
> This appears only to apply if the class is written in Swift. (Is that
>   a correction assumption)?

This is not correct. When you say "use the optional workflow to verify if the method does exist", I assume you mean what happens when you call methods on type `AnyObject` described in "Unrecognized Selectors and Optional Chaining" in the "[id Compatibility](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID42)" section in the Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C guide.

This feature *only* works with Objective-C (`@objc`) methods. `AnyObject` allow you to dynamically access only Objective-C (`@objc`) methods.

> You can call any Objective-C method and access any property on an
>   AnyObject value without casting to a more specific class type. This
>   includes Objective-C compatible methods and properties marked with the
>   @objc attribute.

You cannot use `AnyObject` to call pure Swift (non-`@objc`) methods.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say when a method does exist. I corrected my question.

Comment: @cmarti1138: I have changed the quote to say that