# XMPP buddyWentOnline found nil

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework

I'm trying to program a XMPP client. The connection to my server is OK, but when somebody in my Roster is online, the app is crashing because "buddyWentOnline" unexpectedly found nil?

```
func xmppStream(sender: XMPPStream!, didReceivePresence presence: XMPPPresence!) {
    let presenceType = presence.type()
    let myUsername = sender.myJID.user
    let presenceFromUser = presence.from().user

    if presenceFromUser != myUsername {
        print("Did receive presence from \(presenceFromUser)")
        if presenceType == "available" {
            delegate.buddyWentOnline("\(presenceFromUser)")
        } else if presenceType == "unavailable" {
            delegate.buddyWentOffline("\(presenceFromUser)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you added the implementation for "buddyWentOnline"?

Comment: protocol ChatDelegate {
    func buddyWentOnline(name: String)
    func buddyWentOffline(name: String)
    func didDisconnect()
}

Comment: I used https://github.com/processone/demo-xmpp-ios

Comment: and the `12.After that implement the chat delegates methods:`?

Comment: 12. is written for UITableViewController, but I'm working at AppDelegate

Comment: Check if delegate present before calling it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24167936/2246798

Comment: I tried print("delegate: \(delegate)") and it is nil. But I set it to be nil like the tutorial said. var delegate:ChatDelegate! = nil. How can I change that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake. 
I didn't set the delegate for the initial viewController:

class ViewController: UIViewController, ChatDelegate {

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    appDelegate.delegate = self
}
```