# Xcode 9 RespondsToSelector Issue

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4

NSObject 'responds' method seems to be broken on the latest version of Xcode 9 Beta 4, Swift version 4.0.

Below is an example code tested on Xcode 8 (works fine), on Xcode 9 the method 'responds' returns false for all situations.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class Worker : NSObject
{
    public func work() { }
    public func eat(_ food: AnyObject) { }
    public func sleep(_ hours: Int,_ minutes: Int) { }
}

let worker = Worker()

let canWork = worker.responds(to: Selector(("work")))   // true
let canEat = worker.responds(to: Selector(("eat:")))    // true
let canSleep = worker.responds(to: Selector(("sleep:minutes:")))    // true
let canQuit = worker.responds(to: Selector(("quit")))   // false
```

Example source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/24168825

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44390378/how-can-i-deal-with-objc-inference-deprecation-with-selector-in-swift-4

Comment: Xcode 9 should suggest the modern `#selector(Worker.work)` syntax. And once you use that, the compiler warns: *"argument of '#selector' refers to instance method 'work()' in 'Worker' that depends on '@objc' inference deprecated in Swift 4"*

Comment: @MartinR, I was going to suggest that OP use `#selector` syntax, but then `#selector(quit)` doesn't even compile which negates the ability to do a runtime check.

Comment: @vacawama: You are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the `responds` method.  Due to [SE-0160](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0160-objc-inference.md) which is implemented in Swift 4, these methods are no longer automatically exposed to Objective-C.

If you add `@objc` to the start of *each* method signature (that you want to expose to Objective-C), you will find that `responds` then returns `true`.

```
public class Worker : NSObject
{
    @objc public func work() { }
    @objc public func eat(_ food: AnyObject) { }
    @objc public func sleep(_ hours: Int,_ minutes: Int) { }
}
```

Alternatively, you can also add `@objMembers` to the class to expose *all* of the methods to Objective-C.

```
@objMembers
public class Worker : NSObject
{
    public func work() { }
    public func eat(_ food: AnyObject) { }
    public func sleep(_ hours: Int,_ minutes: Int) { }
}
```

Your third `Selector` syntax is wrong.  It should be `"sleep::"` because the `minutes` label is not used due to the preceding `_`.

Comment: Thanks, for the third syntax it seems it doesn't need the "_" either, so just "sleep::".