# Get a Swift function matching a string

Tags: swift, string, function, introspection

If I have functions in a Swift class like:

```
class MyClass: NSObject {
    class func drawingOne(frame: CGRect) {}
    class func drawingTwo(frame: CGRect) {}
}
```

Note, I can not edit the code in the above class. It is provided by a third party.

How can I pick a function matching a string? For example:

```
let function = function(forName: "drawingOne")
```

to give the function:

```
drawingOne
```

So, I could do something like:

```
guard let drawFunction = function(forName: "drawingOne")
    else { return }
if let drawFunction = drawFunction as? ((CGRect) -> Void) {
    drawFunction(frame: bounds)
}
```

Comment: You will need to create a method that takes a string, switch its value and return the appropriate method based on it.

Comment: I can not edit the class containing the functions. It is provided by a third party. And of course I can create a giant `if`/`then` or `switch`/`case`, mapping each explicit string to a function, but I'm looking for something dynamic.

Comment: You should use `responseToSelector` and `performSelector`. Please check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167791/what-is-the-swift-equivalent-of-respondstoselector

Comment: I can get: `String -> Selector`. But I want `String -> function`. I would settle for: `Selector -> function` since I can obviously chain them.

Comment: I think it is highly possible that this is impossible in Swift. Swift is a _really_ static language...