# Not able to find equivalent of respondsToSelector:@selector(charValue) in Swift 3

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift3

I have done lot of google to find the equivalent of respondsToSelector, still i could find any best solution. kindly suggest me for Any object in Swift3 or 4.

Objetive-C

```
[(id)object respondsToSelector:@selector(charValue)]
```

In Swift we have .method for AnyObject data type but for Any data type

Comment: what is your actual problem scenario? there is probably NO equivalent for swift. the swift approach is different. You may want to convert Obj-C code to swift. So tell something about your actual code base functionality. Did you [check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167791/what-is-the-swift-equivalent-of-respondstoselector/35887129)?

Comment: i have NSNumber * obj where i need to check the                                   
  if ( [obj respondsToSelector:@selector(charValue)] ) { } same need to be converted to swift

Answer (score 2):

you should first type cast then use

```
(object as? Type)?.charValue()
```

if your `object` is not of a type then it `nil` and never call the `charValue()`

Answer (score 2):

Reason: You can not write `respondsToSelector` for the swift-based function. There are 2 reasons.

1) In Objective-c, we do have `charValue` property in `NSNumber` class along with `initWithChar`. Whereas in swift we do not have any such properties in `NSNumber` class.

```
@property (readonly) char charValue;

- (NSNumber *)initWithChar:(char)value NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
```

2) `respondsToSelector` only accepts Objective-C functions in argument.

Try with writing `responds(to: #selector` on `NSNumber` and you will found that it only accepts objective-c function and we don't have any such method in Swift `NSNumber` class.

```
let numb: NSNumber?
numb?.responds(to: #selector(@objc method))
```

***Rather, You can use the swift string conversion of NSNumber, as:***

```
let number: NSNumber?
let numberString = number?.stringValue ?? "" 
// Added default variable "" in case of string conversion becomes nil
```